# Firefox Page - Navigation with Touchpad

Tags: 14.04, gnome, firefox, navigation

Hy, i' m using a Lenovou330p notebook with Ubuntu 14.04.1 and GNOME 3.

I tried to find out how to be able to navigate back and foreward in Firefox with 3 or 4 finger swipe gestures on the Touchpad but failed so far.

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the ui.trackpoint_hack.enabled pref on the about:config page from the default value -1 to 0 or 1 to see if that makes the touch pad work.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/about:config

Close and restart Firefox after changing the ui.trackpoint_hack.enabled pref.

ui.trackpoint_hack.enabled (default:-1) (-1:autodetect;0:off;1:on)

Comment: Ok thanks, i gonna play around with the gesture values in the about:config.